# Unable to insert data from PLC into MongoDB using Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, sockets, pymongo, plc

I want to insert data(a string - `'Hello World'`) from PLC into MongoDB using Pymongo. I cannot figure out why a collection isn't being created and `'Hello World'` is not inserted into it. Could you please explain as to where I am going wrong? Here's the code I have written so far:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import socket         
    import socket
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    import datetime

    # Connection to server (PLC) PLC's IP addr is .135
    server = socket.socket()         
    host = '10.52.124.135' 
    port = 4840  

    server.connect((host, port))
    print server.recv(1024)

    server.close 

    #Connection to Client (Mongodb) on port 27017
    IP = '10.52.124.186'
    PORT = 27017
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

    client = MongoClient('10.52.124.186', 27017)
    db = client.RXMMongoDB
    collection = db.ABC

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((IP, PORT))
    s.listen(1)

    # connections loop
    while True:
            conn, addr = s.accept()
            print 'Connection address:',addr
            try:
                     # read loop
                     while True:
                          data = server.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)

                          if not data: 
                                  break

                          # send to Mongo
                          mongodoc = { "data": data, "date" : datetime.datetime.utcnow() }
                          db.ABC.insert_one(mongodoc)
            finally:
                     conn.close()
```

Comment: What version of mongo?

Comment: @GeorgePetrov PyMongo 3.2, MongoDB 2.6, Python 2.7.

Comment: @GeorgePetrov Sorted that mistake now. I have named the server on MongoDB as 'GDS'. Should I mention that explicitly in the code or just the server IP address is sufficient?

Comment: But how did you name your `db` and `collection`?

Comment: @GeorgePetrov Name of `DB` is GDS for which the `IP Address` is `10.52.124.186`  and I have used:


    `db.RXMMongoDB.ABC.insert_one(mongodoc)`


So even if I haven't named a `collection`, ABC will be created as a collection right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But you need to use `db.ABC.insert_one(monodic)` cause by that line `db = client.RXMMongoDB` you already called the db.

Comment: @GeorgePetrov Ah, the typo again. Added the RXMMongoDB in the insert statement by mistake. So, I don't need to include the name of the DB(GDS in this case)? Because I tried `db.ABC.insert_one(mongodoc)` and still, I can't seem to find it in the database.

Comment: Just try with `db.ABC.insert(mongodoc)` according to docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.insert/

Comment: @GeorgePetrov nope, it didn't work too.

Comment: How are you querying the database to see if the insert occurred? I suspect you are querying on a different collection than the one you inserted into.

Comment: Hi @BernieHackett, the `db.ABC.insert_one(mongodoc)` should do it right? Even if I haven't created a collection called ABC, I'm guessing data should be inserted into ABC collection under RXMMongoDB database. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your code example only shows you inserting documents into MongoDB, not querying for those documents. You say that the inserts don't work. How do you know? What query are you doing that proves that the insert didn't create a collection?

Comment: @BernieHackett Since I am using MongoVUE which is a GUI interface for MongoDB, it shows the available databases and collections in real time. Whenever a database is created or a collection is inserted, it's possible to see the same on MongoVUE.

Comment: @Arjun The current version of MongoVUE (1.6.9) hasn't been updated since Jan-2014 and isn't fully compatible with newer versions of MongoDB (3.0+). Can you check for your documents using the `mongo` shell to ensure the issue isn't with MongoVUE?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this help you?

```
import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('1.2.3.4',27017)
db = client.dbTest
data = "Hello SO World"
mongodoc = { "data": data, "date" : datetime.datetime.utcnow() }
db.myCollection.insert(mongodoc)
```

Once you get your PLC data, you might want to check the content of your 'data' variable too?

Comment: Hi @Brandon, 

the `data = "Hello SO World"` statement is already given as input in the PLC. Do I have to give it as input once again in the .py code?

Comment: No @Arjun, I was just showing that as a sample to insert in Mongo.  I think your TCP socket server code is OK in principle, though I'm not sure what format of data comes back from your PLC.  So you could try changing your 'insert_one()' Mongo function to 'insert()'.  But...I see TCP port 4840 in your code; if you're trying to act as a OPC-UA server with this code, you'll probably need to go a different route and find the appropriate OPC-UA libraries.

Comment: Hi @brandon, the input data is given as a string and there is no data conversion taking in the PLC. Also, for the server part of the code, I tried running it on the localhost 27017 port but then I get a 'connection actively refused' error despite disabling the firewall and antivirus.